# Hierarchical Forecasting using exogenous variables at each sub level

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am newbie, exploring some concepts for Hierarchical Forecasting using exogenous variables. I am stuck at obtaining an efficient approach where I have to incorporate exogenous variables at each sub level.

Example:
I need to forecast volume of inventory for an garment industry at country level. This industry has multiple levels of hierarchy for their stores like -

1st Level - zones (East, West, North etc.,)
2nd Level - States in each zone
3rd Level - Cities in each state
4th Level - Stores in each cities
5th Level - Male /Female
6th Level - Sizes (L/M/S)

I have exogenous variables at almost each level. The traditional models like PyAF, seer, htsprophet and hts package in R doesn't allow me to provide these exogenous variables at each level. Other approach I thought was to build traditional time series at each level for each entity (this is not an efficient solution).

Any thoughts are welcome and highly appreciated.

Comment: Good luck in the M6 competition!

Comment: This scenario I have come across not just in some competitions but also in some business requirements. Hence the question, by the way, I am not in this M6 competition.